# How can I make the entire image clickable on my wordpress.org site?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Right now my posts can only be clicked by clicking the title, but I would love for the entire image to link to each individual post.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('card-box col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'); ?>>
    <div class="card" data-background="image" data-src="<?php esc_url( the_post_thumbnail_url( 'large' ) ); ?>">
             <div class="header">
                    <?php
                    $categories = get_the_category();
                    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                    ?>                                                          
                        <div class="category">
                            <h6>
                                <span class="category">
                                    <?php  echo '<a class="category" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>'; ?>
                                </span>
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>                        
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <?php the_title( '<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h4>' ); ?>
                    <span class="date"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_date() ); ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="filter"></div>
                </div> <!-- end card -->
        </article>
```

I don't want to use js because I've been told that's not SEO friendly.

I've tried using the  tag from the entry-title and surrounding the whole div with that same link, but it did not work.

Comment: What have you tried? Ultimately you need the link to surround the entire div that contains the image. Or you can setup an event listener for the click.

Answer (score 2):

That's how it is done in HTML:

```
<a href="...">
    <img alt="..." src="..." />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work if the rest of the code works. What I did: I copied the `<a>` tag from the `h4` element (the post title) and put it around the image (lines 2-4, no other changes in original code):

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'card-box col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'); ?>>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="card" data-background="image" data-src="<?php esc_url( the_post_thumbnail_url( 'large' ) ); ?>">
    </a>
  <div class="header">
    <?php
                    $categories = get_the_category();
                    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                    ?>
      <div class="category">
        <h6>
          <span class="category">
                                    <?php  echo '<a class="category" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>'; ?>
                                </span>
        </h6>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <?php the_title( '<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h4>' ); ?>
    <span class="date"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_date() ); ?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="filter"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- end card -->
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I'm really stuck here. Your suggestion at least didn't break the page, but for some reason that link in the <a> tag won't populate. <a>href="" rel="bookmark"</a> is how it shows up when I try to load the page. No URL there even though the title href is populating just fine. But also, even when I manually add the correct URL to that tag in the developers console, it still doesn't allow me to click the image.

Comment: I changed my answer, try the new (simpler) version (it uses `<?php the_permalink(); ?>`)

Comment: WOW you're so close! The correct link is populating now, but still can't click. For some reason the when I look at the code in the dev console it seems to have duplicated the <a> tag so the whole <a>and closing </a> tags show before and after the div. When I highlight the link, it says it is 0 x 22 somewhere right above the image

Comment: maybe try to remove the div tag of the image itself and just use `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?></a>`. (might display the image without its intended CSS, but could be a step forward)

Comment: no luck. I think it might be because the title and the category links are positioned within the image div. I'm wondering if maybe it isn't possible to have the background image of a div be a clickable link without interfering with the other links in the div

Comment: oh the image is just a background image in that DIV? I hadn't realized that! And there are links in there? Well, of course a link can't wrap other links. But my last version (`echo get_the_post_thumbnail() `) should actually just display the image itself (in an img tag, not as a background image)

Comment: I saw your new question... Still, to continue here: You could change the content of that to-be-clickable DIV to contain the tile etc. not as links, but as simple text DIVs. Then you can wrap the whole DIV with an `a` tag as I suggested and make it clickable - the former links (inside the DIV) are still clickable since now the whole thing is clickable...

Comment: The only problem with this is that there is still a category link that is linking to a different page. Look at the picture i included on the new post.

Comment: I appreciate you following along. I didn't mean to give up on you before. I just wanted to try rephrasing the question to see if it could help at all

Comment: well, then (if the category link has to remain) there won't be a solution

Comment: I've seen this done elsewhere though. I will try to look for an example I suppose

Comment: the only thing I can think of is to put the category link in an absolutely positioned DIV that is placed over the image, but you'd have to place it outside that linked div in the HTML code and move it over the image using CSS.

Comment: hmmm that just might be the solution. Maybe I'll find a spot above or below the image where itll look alright