# Make background image clickable with other links and elements inside the same div

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Right now the code below generates the content seen here:

[image: Example image]

Currently the title has to be clicked for the post page to be loaded, but I want to allow the entire background image to be clickable. Is this possible? I've tried surrounding the card div with the  tag from the title code, but that still did not let me click the background image like a link.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('card-box col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'); ?>>
    <div class="card" data-background="image" data-src="<?php esc_url( the_post_thumbnail_url( 'large' ) ); ?>">
             <div class="header">
                    <?php
                    $categories = get_the_category();
                    if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                    ?>                                                          
                        <div class="category">
                            <h6>
                                <span class="category">
                                    <?php  echo '<a class="category" href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>'; ?>
                                </span>
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>                        
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <?php the_title( '<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h4>' ); ?>
                    <span class="date"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_date() ); ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="filter"></div>
                </div> <!-- end card -->
        </article>
```

Comment: You also want to link category name to the category page?

Comment: Yes I want to keep that category link if possible. And every other spot on that card div should link to the post. Avoiding js if possible too

Comment: This is a continuation of your question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/43058846/5641669 - why don't you just edit/expand the original question?

Comment: You could add an `<img>` tag within a link.  Just make sure the link does not contain anything other than the image.  You can then add the proper CSS styling to make the image _appear_ as if it is a background image (such as using absolute positioning or z-index).  That would be the way I would do it, but you might find another way.  I hope this helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery approach like below

```
$('.card').on('click', function(event){
  var elementTag = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
  if(elementTag === 'div') {
     var pageurl = $(this).find('.entry-title a').attr('href');
     window.location.href = pageurl;
  }
});`
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted jQuery approach before reading your comment to not using JS. If you're concerned with SEO, I am not sure if the above code will affect your SEO.

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible to have links within a link without using JS. I will follow this question if someone's got an answer